# What is the usecase of `PassBy` trait bound

Tags: runtime, wasm, scale-codec, host-functions

While working on types between Runtime and Host functions, types going from Runtime to host function requires a PassBy trait bound while types going from Host function to Runtime does not need that trait bound. My guess is that they are directly referencing the WASM memory rather than copying while other way round requires a copying of the type into WASM memory. If so, why not use the Codec's Encode and Decode directly, then?